# Automating Autofill in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, excel-auto-fill

Is there a way to automate autofill in Excel with say a function or something along those lines? I need a function I currently have to autofill down a certain number of rows depending on the user's input but all I can find on google says to use the autofill handle which will not work for what I need.
Any help is appreciated.

Can I have a function autofill down a certain number of rows automatically? As in, when a user inputs a number of rows, it automatically fills the function that amount of rows.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is that more clear? I've been struggling with this for a while so I'm having difficulty putting the issue to words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this works:

[image]

`SEQUENCE()` is a spill formula, enumerating a desired sequence.

`IF` simply test if an item in the sequence array is less than desired range if yes it will perform the formula.

another option is to use `Row()` in place of sequence, but it may be harder to work with (especially if someone accidentally inserts rows)

If this isn't what you are lookong for then clarify your question.

Comment: That is essentially what I was looking for, that technique helped me get part of it done. I wound up just using the autofill drag handle and hiding all data further down from the number of rows the user input. Thank you for your help.